# Por que não está inserindo os dados no sqlite e como inserir imagens?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, bootstrap-3, sqlite3

Estou fazendo um sistema, segui todos os passos para inserir os dados na tabela usando o sqlite, mas quando vou para a Application na parte de inspecionar o elemento do browser o banco continua vazio. Também gostaria de saber o que fazer no código para que uma imagem seja inserida...

JS com sqlite:

```
    var db = openDatabase("Meubanco", "3.0", "Mybase", 6000);
    db.transaction(function(criar){
    criar.executeSql("CREATE TABLE granjas (codigo PRIMARY KEY, nome TEXT, email TEXT, cnpj TEXT)")
});

    function cadastrar(){
    var codigo = document.getElementById("codigo").value;
    var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var cnpj = document.getElementById("cnpj").value;

    db.transaction(function(armazenar){
    armazenar.executeSql("INSERT INTO granjas (codigo, nome, email, cnpj) VALUES (?,?,?@email.com,?)", [codigo, nome, email, cnpj]);
});
    alert("Granja " + document.getElementById("nome").value + " Cadastrada!");
};
```

HTML

```
<form onsubmit="cadastrar();">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Código</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="codigo" placeholder="codigo">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Nome</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" placeholder="nome">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Endereço de email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>CNPJ</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cnpj" placeholder="cnpj">
  </div>
  <form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Insira uma imagem da granja<small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Ação Opcional.</small></label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="imagem_da_empresa"/>
  </div>
  </form>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="cadastrar();">Cadastrar</button>
```

Creio que esteja bem claro o que estou tentando fazer... Alguém sabe onde está o erro?

Comment: está faltando o tipo de dados do campo "codigo" no seu comando pra criar a tabela

Comment: Verdade! mas inseri aqui e após recarregar a página continua sem salvar as alterações no banco.

Answer (score 0):

Se você colocar a coluna `codigo` apenas PRIMARY KEY deve informar um valor na inserção. Se caso você não deseja informa um valor na coluna  é só colocar a coluna AUTOINCREMENT

`CREATE TABLE granjas  (codigo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nome TEXT,  email TEXT,  cnpj TEXT );`

Comment: Editei aqui. O browser continua dizendo que a tabela está vazia após inserir os dados :/